# Como filtrar uma lista de objetos? Como posso escrever melhor esse metodo?

Tags: java

Gostaria de escrever esse metodo de uma forma mais limpa e que tivesse maior desempenho. Alguém tem uma ideia?

```
private List<Projeto> filtraResultado(List<Projeto> projetosAssinados, String[] filtros){
    List<Projeto> result = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
    for(Projeto p: projetosAssinados) {
        if(existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getDsProjeto(), filtros) ||
           existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getNomeProjeto(), filtros) ||
           existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getSetor(),filtros) ||
           existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getUn(), filtros) ||
           existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getProcessosModelados(),filtros)||
           existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getServicosPrestados(),filtros) ||
           existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getTecnologias(),filtros)||
           existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(p.getDetalhamento(),filtros)) {
                result.add(p);
        }

    }
    return result;
}

public boolean existeFiltroBuscadoNosCamposDePesquisa(String campoPesquisado,String[] filtros ){
    if(campoPesquisado == null) {
        return false;
    }
    for(String f: filtros) {
        if(StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(campoPesquisado, f.trim())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Acredito ser possível implementar isso com bem menos linhas de código e com código mais reutilizável, e possivelmente usando paralelismo para aumentar a performance. Entretanto, fazer em menos linhas da forma como estou pensando pode atrapalhar a performance. O que você considera mais importante nesse caso, desempenho ou código mais simples e reutilizável?

Comment: Você está utilizando Java 8?

Comment: sim estou utilizando java 8, até pensei em utilizar stream, mas acontece que é um for dentro de outro

Comment: Eu reescrevi utilizando menos linhas e menos codigo reescrito, mas acredito q ainda é possível melhorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Duas otimizações possíveis

1. Desnecessariamente é executada f.trim() inúmeras vezes, além de gerar objetos desnecessários. Melhor seria tratar todos os filtros inicialmente e simplesmente reutilizá-los, posteriormente.
2. Se o conjunto de projetos é significativo, então parece que o caminho é executar o *stream* sugerido anteriormente de forma paralela (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel).

Comment: ótima dica, obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Projeto> filtraResultado(List<Projeto> projetosAssinados, String[] filtros) {
    List<Projeto> result = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
    boolean contains;

    Set< String > filterSet = Arrays.asList(filtros).stream( ).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    for (Projeto p : projetosAssinados) {

        List<String> toCheckList  = Arrays.asList(
                p.getDsProjeto(), p.getNomeProjeto(),
                p.getSetor(), p.getUn(), 
                p.getProcessosModelados(), p.getServicosPrestados(), 
                p.getTecnologias(), p.getDetalhamento());

        contains = toCheckList
                 .stream( )
                 .anyMatch( list -> filterSet.stream( )
                 .anyMatch(filter -> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase( list, filter)));

        if(contains) {
            result.add(p);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Não seria melhor concatenar a lista "toCheckList " em uma String? Acredito que concatenado em uma String você diminui um pouco esse excesso de código e terá o mesmo resultado. Quando for concatenar só lembre de deixar um espaço, ou um carácter especial para não modificar a lógica.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Teste teste = new Teste();
        List<Projeto> projetos = new ArrayList<>();
        Projeto projeto = new Projeto("0002", "Teste", "TI", "457", "254", "Consultoria"
                , "Java", "Testes unitarios");
        Projeto projeto1 = new Projeto("0003", "Locomocao", "TI", "784", "145", "Consultoria"
                , "Java", "Testes unitarios");
        Projeto projeto2 = new Projeto("0005", "Locomocao124", "TI", "784", "547", "Consultoria"
                , "Python", "Testes funcional");

        projetos.add(projeto);
        projetos.add(projeto1);
        projetos.add(projeto2);

        String[] filtros = {"123", "Java", "145"};

        List<Projeto> list = teste.filtraResultado(projetos, filtros);

        for (Projeto projeto3: list) {
            System.out.println(projeto3);
        }


    }


    private List<Projeto> filtraResultado(List<Projeto> projetosAssinados, String[] filtros) {
        List<Projeto> projetoList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Projeto projeto : projetosAssinados) {
            for (String filtro : filtros) {
                if (projeto.toString().contains(filtro)) {
                    projetoList.add(projeto);
                }
            }

        }
        return projetoList;
    }
```